# Consulta sobre promesas en AngularJS (Angular 1)

Tags: angularjs

Buenas mi duda es la siguiente, estoy tratando de obtener la `data` desde una `api` que esta en `url`, uso `$http.get`, lo asigno a `$scope.ips` y me muestra los datos en el `console.log()` respectivo, ahora el problema se que `$http.get` es una promesa así que te retorna los datos una vez que están disponibles, pero dado que quisiera hacer lo siguiente imprimir los datos fuera del `$http.get` , como podría hacerlo , pues intento hacerlo y me sale el objeto vacío,sé que es un ejemplo simple , pero me ha tocado en otros proyectos consultar datos de una `api`, y a partir de los datos de esa `api`, consultar otra vez datos en ella formando un código espagueti interminable.

```
var app=angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("main",function($scope,$http){
$scope.ips={};

var url="http://ip-api.com/json/208.80.152.201";


$http.get(url)
.success(function(data){

    $scope.ips=data;
console.log($scope.ips)

});

console.log($scope.ips);


})
```

Por ejemplo si quisiera hacer algo otra consulta dentro de la misma consulta asi sucesivamente así como ven va aumentando el tamaño del código como podría modularizarlo.

```
var app=angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("main",function($scope,$http){
$scope.ips={};

var url="http://ip-api.com/json/208.80.152.201";


$http.get(url)
.success(function(data){

    $scope.ips=data;
    console.log($scope.ips)
    var url2="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"+data.city;
    $http.get(url2)
    ...
    ....
});

console.log($scope.ips);


})
```

Comment: Por que no usas un **factory** o un **service**, y lo llamas en el **controller**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que entiendo es que necesitas ejecutar mas acciones después de recibir ciertas respuestas asíncronas y efectivamente como dices si ejecutas el código encadenado terminaras con un [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/) para ello se usa las promesas. Te muestro un ejemplo de como puedes encadenar tus promesas para que tu código no tenga demasiada indentación.

Siguiendo tu código después de recibir la respuesta de la primera petición, lanzo otra petición y regreso la promesa ($http.get()) para que el siguiente 'then' pueda encadenarse con la segunda petición.

```
var app=angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("main",function($scope,$http){
  $scope.ips={};

  var url="http://ip-api.com/json/208.80.152.201";
  $http.get(url)
   .then(function(res){
     $scope.ips=res.data;
     console.log($scope.ips.isp) //wikimedia foundation
     //var url2="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"+data.city;
     var url2 = "http://ip-api.com/json/8.8.8.8"; //otro link de ejemplo pero aquí ya puedes usar la información del primer request.
     return $http.get(url2); // otro request
  }).then(function(resFromUrl2) { // información que proviene de otro request
    console.log(resFromUrl2.data.isp); // google.
  }); // podrías agregar mas promesas encadenadas con las respuestas anteriores.
});
```

Te dejo el ejemplo completo en [codepen](http://codepen.io/uriel_tzel/pen/WojEEz)

Comment: gracias ya lo entendi